# Canvas in visualforce page is not capturing data when used in touch screen devices

Tags: visualforce, javascript, canvas, html5, touch

I have a requirement to capture user's signature using `<canvas>` and save it to a record. It is working with mouse but not when using touch screen devices like mobile phones. Below is my code:

```
<div style="width:38%;margin:0 auto;" align="center">
                            <apex:pageBlock >
                                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!fieldSetsCase}" var="a">
                                        <apex:inputField label="{!a.label}" value="{!objCase[a.fieldPath]}" styleClass="{!a.fieldPath} slds-input"/><br/>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                                <div data-role="page" id="signatureCaptureHome" align="right">
                                    <div data-role="content">
                                        <h1 id="recordSigId" align="left" style="margin-left:30px;height:5px">Signature</h1>
                                        <canvas id="signatureCanvas" height="140px" width="435px" style="border:1px solid #000000;margin-right:5px;"/><br/>
                                        <canvas id="blank" height="140px" width="435px" style="display:none"/>
                                    </div> 
                                </div><br/>

                                <input type="button" id="clearSignButton"  name="clear" onclick="clearSign();" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" value="Clear Signature"/>
                                <input type="reset" id="clearButton" name="reset" align="right" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" style="margin-left:10px" />
                                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" align="right" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" style="margin-left:10px" />
                            </apex:pageBlock>

                        </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas;
        var context;
        var drawingUtil;
        var isDrawing = false;
        var prevX, prevY, currX, currY = 0;

        function DrawingUtil() {    
            isDrawing = false;   
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);   
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop, false);    
            w = canvas.width;
            h = canvas.height;
        }

        //Start Event for Signature Captuare on Canvas
        function start(event) {    
            event.preventDefault();
            isDrawing = true;    
            prevX = currX;    
            prevX = currY;    
            currX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;    
            currY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            context.beginPath();    
            context.fillStyle = "cadetblue";    
            context.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            context.closePath();
        }

        //Event while someone is drawing to caputre the path while they draw
        function draw(event) {    
            event.preventDefault();    

            if (isDrawing) {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
                context.lineTo(currX, currY);
                context.strokeStyle = "cadetblue";
                context.lineWidth = "2";
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();    
            }   
        }

        //Event when someone stops drawing their signature line
        function stop(event) {    
            if (isDrawing) {
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
                isDrawing = false;    
            }   
        }

        function clearSign() {    
            context.clearRect(0,0,w,h);   
        }

        canvas = document.getElementById("signatureCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.strokeStyle = "#FFF";
        context.lineWidth = "2";
        drawingUtil = new DrawingUtil(canvas);

        function callMethod() {
            var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
            strDataURI = strDataURI.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            console.log('strDataURI', strDataURI);
            callClass(strDataURI);
        }

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(){
            if(canvas.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()){

                var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("toast");
                divs[0].classList.remove('slds-hide');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("toast");
                    divs[0].classList.add('slds-hide');
                }, 3000); 

            } else {
                callMethod();
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Do I miss something important here that's causing it not to work with touch screens? Any help will be appreciated.